# android TextView selected option

Tags: android, textview

Currently I am displaying two texts in the activity.
e.g.: "Group 1" and "Group 2".

I let user select the text (just like a button).

I need to find out whether the above displayed text is selected or not and then change the background color.
Here is the code I use for that. tv.isSelected() always evaluates to 'false'. Can any body tell me what I am doing wrong.
Is the "isSelected()" method used for a different purpose than how I use it?

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);     
textView.setText("Group 1");

textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) view;

    if (tv.isSelected()) {
       tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);                   
    } else {                
       tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

   }
});
linearLayout.addView(textView);
```

Comment: You want to switch between blue and white every time it is clicked right? Why not using a flag?

Answer (score 3):

Try to do the following:

```
if (tv.getId() == textBox1Id) { 
      firstSelected = true; 
} else { firstSelected = false; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
OnCreate()
{
  TextView textView = new TextView(this);
  textView.setText("Group 1");

  textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      textView.setSelected(true);
    }
  });

  if (textView.isSelected()) {
    textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);                   
  } else {                
    textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
  }
  linearLayout.addView(textView);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `boolean` variable to handle this:

```
private boolean tvSelected = false;
```

Your onClick method would change:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);     
textView.setText("Group 1");

textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
    if (tvSelected) {
       textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); 
       tvSelected = false;                  
    else {
       tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
       tvSelected = true;
   }
});
linearLayout.addView(textView);
```

In terms of **isSelected()** usage, according to the API documentation:

> A view can be selected or not. Note that selection is not the same as
>   focus. Views are typically selected in the context of an AdapterView
>   like ListView or GridView; the selected view is the view that is
>   highlighted.